# How is Android GenieWidget updated?

Tags: android, widget

The Android GenieWidget (also known as News & Weather Widget) updates very often (every few seconds). Now the time interval for updating a widget can currently not be shorter than half an hour. It is possible to create a service or use AlarmManager that updates it more often, but this is discouraged because of the drain of system resources.

I am considering making a similar application. My question is, how is it (probably) done in GenieWidget? Is it some clever trick, or does it just update more frequently (and is therefore battery drainer)? That would be weird since it is Google application and one expects some quality there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I think most likely scenario is this:

1. Updates of news and weather data from the Internet (news.google.com and other sites) every hour
2. Frequent updates to the widget (every few seconds) by a service that is probably started on receiving the ACTION_SCREEN_ON intent (which however should not be used lightly as its excessive use by applications and services could significantly slow down the system when turnin screen on).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you're getting the information that the Widget checks data more often than 30 minutes. Just check the interval in the settings.

But if you have to do that - why not use another event except a scheduled interval like display turned on?

Comment: Well, I'm not saying that it checks for data, just that it gets updated (text changes) every few seconds (it is visible on the screen). Using another event is an interesting idea, could you elaborate on that? Would it consume less system resources?

Comment: Just use a broadcast receiver for different system events. Display turned on is really good for that

Comment: I will try it, thanks. But what about the original question? GenieWidget is from Google, stock e.g. on Nexus S. Could it be "carelessly" implemented? I guess it is possible since it consumes as much battery on my phone as web browser, but I would be glad if someone could confirm it.